# Create an array of hash values in order of this weeks date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a view that displays uses a five element array to display some numbers where the elements relate to mon,tue,wed,thur,fri
`[100,200,50,300,200]`

this is built ( not very cleanly) by the method

```
    def this_weeks_sales
        x = self.sales.where(sale_date: (Date.today.beginning_of_week..(Date.today.beginning_of_week + 5)))
   .group("DATE(sales.sale_date)").sum("sales.amount").sort.to_h.values.in_groups_of(5,0)[0]
end
```

> If there are no sales for a day it should have '0' as that element and
>   always have 5 elements for mon-friday

I've run some tests and it's not working as I thought it would, if there is a £100 sale for tuesday but nothing for monday then I get the array `[100,0,0,0,0]` instead of the expected `[0,100,0,0,0]` i.e the first sale of the week will always be element[0]

I don't want to change all my views, how can I get the desired output?

```
self.sales.where(sale_date: (Date.today.beginning_of_week..(Date.today.beginning_of_week + 5)))
    .group("DATE(sales.sale_date)").sum("sales.amount").sort.to_h
```

returns a hash e.g from the example above if there's only a sale on tuesday `{Tue, 28 Jul 2015=>100}`

Comment: you could try `.order(sales_date: :desc)` which will order it by the sales date instead of using sort

Comment: @PhilVarg that makes no difference

Comment: why are you calling `.sort` .? that will sort the output based on the amount order

Comment: @Athar no,  sort on a hash sorts by the key

Comment: sorry yes you are right. i just tried your scenario and output is not ordered. but my output results in key value. Does your key is monday and output is 100.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ETA: You're grouping and sorting correctly, but then transforming the sorted array back into a hash and pulling the (unordered) values. You just need to leave it as an array and `map` it to the sum:

```
sales.where(sale_date: Time.zone.now.all_week).group("DATE(sales.sale_date)").sum(:amount).sort_by{|date,sum| date}.map{|date,sum| sum}
```

Edit 2: If you want to get 0 for dates that don't exist in the database, you'll have to loop through the desired dates:

```
daily_sale_totals = sales.where(sale_date: Date.today.all_week).group("DATE(sales.sale_date)").sum(:amount)
Date.today.all_week.map{|date| daily_sale_totals[date] || 0}
```

Comment: that would give me the array [100] not the expected [0,100,0,0,0]

Comment: @raphael_turtle Edited with code to get that desired output